# How do you filter a mat-table that has an array in it?

Tags: angular, mongodb, filter, datasource, mat-table

I have a table with 4 displayed columns(email-firstname-lastname-skills) stored in a dataSource,
one of them is the column "Skills" and it's an array, these four columns are extracted from a database, the model for the User is

```
Email [string]
firstname [string]
lastname [string]
skills 
{
 skill(id - reference to _id){
            _id: [id]
            name: [string]
          }
}
```

I tried using the filter from the angular tutorial without luck

I tried with this code here

```
    applyFilter(filterValue: string, abc: string) {
        // this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
        // console.log(this.dataSource.filter)
        const re =  { $regex: new RegExp(filterValue).source, $options:'gi' };



        this.userService.getUsers({
          '$or': [
            { firstname: re} ,
            { lastname: re },
            { email: re },
            { 'skills.skill.name': re }
            ]



        }).subscribe(users => {
          this.dataSource.data = users;
          // console.log(users)
        })
      }
```

I expect the filter to work on the whole table but instead the code works on all columns besides the "Skills" column, any Idea?

Update:

[db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crgeh.png)

in that image there is my mongodb structure, is there a way to auto fill the field 'Skillname' via the field 'Skill' that refers to another db structure?

Comment: Please provide an example like Stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Since you use observables, take advantage of it :

```
data$ = this.userService.getUsers(...);
search = new FormControl('');
dataSource$ = combineLatest(
  this.search.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('')),
  this.data$
).pipe(
  map(([query, arr]) => arr.filter(item => item.XXX.includes(query)))
);
```

Now you have an Observable containing only the filtered results. You can either subscribe to it and create your data from it, or use an `async` pipe in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the filter was actually working because I was saving the objectID and not a string, so i changed that and all worked just fine